# postgres sql select combination of two columns

Tags: sql

A user can choose a list of option combinations and then search for them.

The sql could look like this.

```
select * from p where (option_type = 'X' and value = 'A') 
or (option_type = 'X' and value = 'B')
or (option_type = 'Y' and value = 'D')
```

But of course I do not want to have n number of or's

How would a good sql look like that performs ??? The user can choose many option combinations.

Thanks.

Comment: that might be the best way... and the logic is clear for readability.  you can make a table (maybe temp) to store those values and join on it...  why is an `OR` for each possible condition unacceptable?

Comment: you could try..... `WHERE (option_type = 'X' and value in ('A','B')) or (option_type = 'Y' and value in ('D', ... )`

Comment: But that would also give me many or's.
The user could possible choose hundreds of options

Comment: Are these pairs stored somewhere?  Is their a rule for generating them?

Comment: what's the limit for the number of `or`s that is acceptable?  i'm not sure there's another way besides storing the pair combinations in a table and joining on those values.  maybe... if you provide us with sample data, table structure, where these combinations come from and example input there's a better approach someone can suggest

Comment: The possible pair combination are static, the user can choose from that list, in the ui it is a picklist. 
X : A
X : B
Y : D
etc.

Comment: I was thinking that many or's would be bad for performance.. but I actually have no idea ?

Comment: I'm not sure how else you want to do it.  Unless you provide some context of the data and what you're trying to get and what you have available to you, I can't really suggest any other way besides storing the pairs in a table and using that to join.  The thing I don't understand... is.. if they the user can pick any combination of these two lists (`ThingA` and `ThingB`), why are you filtering the query for these combinations... if any combination can exist......

Comment: to be continued from my last comment: and if you're not looking for a specific combination or a set of combinations... just any and all combinations... I dunno.  `or` isn't bad if you need it and there really isn't a better way if that's what is actually needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No need for multiple ORs:

```
select * 
from p 
where (option_type, value) in ( ('X' ,'A'), ('X','B'), ('Y','D') )
```

Comment: Oh I need a little more explanation.
So I have a product that has some options.  

One product could have option X,A and X,B and Y,D.

select * from product 
join product_option on product.id = product_option.product_id 
where (option_type, value) in ( ('X' ,'A'), ('X','B'), ('Y', 'D') ) 

so would not give me the right result...

Comment: @user2073955: my query is equivalent to the one in your question. It solves the "*I do not want to have n number of or's" question. If you need something different you should add some sample data and the expected output.